# How to find out the rows affected in SQL Profiler or trace?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, trace, sql-server-profiler

I'm using tracing to log all delete or update queries run through the system. The problem is, if I run a query like `DELETE FROM [dbo].[Artist] WHERE ArtistId>280`, I know how many rows were deleted but I'm unable to find out which rows were deleted (the data they had).

I'm thinking of doing this as a logging system so it would be useful to see which rows were affected and what data they had if at all possible. I don't really want to use triggers for this job but I will if I have to (and if it's feasible).

Comment: The SQL Profiler is only going to show you the operations which have been carried out on the database, I don't think it can show you values from deleted records after they're deleted - I think you'd have to use triggers for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the original data and are planning on storing all the deleted data in a separate table why not just logically delete the original data rather than physically delete it? i.e.

```
UPDATE dbo.Artist SET Artist_deleted = 1 WHERE ArtistId>280
```

Then you only need add one column to your current table rather than creating new tables and scripts to support these. You could then partition the current table based on the deleted flag if you are worried about disk space/performance etc.

Comment: Might also be worth setting a `DateDeleted` value at the same time. In fact there are a bunch of different values you might want to store on deletion as an audit.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the way to go. I'll also need to add a DateDeleted as @3N1GM4 said but it's the basic logic behind it. (Database is not mine but they were talking about implementing the same thing, so it's all good imho.)